# Simple function that execute an instruction every X time until Y condition is accomplished

Tags: kotlin

What do you think about this implementation?

```
inline fun every(duration: Long, timeUnit: TimeUnit, whileCondition: () -> Boolean = { true }, function: () -> Unit) {
    while (whileCondition()) {
        function()
        Thread.sleep(timeUnit.toMillis(duration))
    }
}
```

This allows calling the following statement:

```
every(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS){
    println("Hello world")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually it's a bad idea to put to sleep whole thread. I'd recommend use Java `Timer` or kotlin's wrapper for it.

Here is an example:

```
fixedRateTimer("default", false, 0L, 1000){
    println("Hello!")
    if (theEndIsNear) cancel()
}
```